# After GraphQL Query: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo

I was using graphql mutations like this and the .then & .catch work perfectly:

```
  let submitForm = (
    email: string,
    firstName: string
  ) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);

    if (email && (firstName)) {
      const input: UpdateUserInput = {};
      if (firstName) {
        input.firstName = firstName;
      }
      updateUser({
        variables: {
          email: email,
          input: input,
        },
      })
        .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<UpdateUserResponse>) => {
          if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
            setIsUpdated(true);
          }
        })
        .catch((error: { message: string }) => {
          console.log('Error msg:' + error.message);
        });
    }
  };
```

Now I am doing something similar here for a graphql query (fuller working version below):

```
let ShowUsers = () => {
    const where: WhereInput = {};
    if (criteria === '2') {
      if (searchItem) {
        where.firstName_contains = searchItem;
        loadUsers({
          variables: {
            where: where
          },
        })
        .then(({ data }: any) => {
          if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
          }
        })
      }
    }
}
```

but I keep getting an error on then that `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'`

Edit:

Without the .then, .catch, my code works correctly. Full form is something like this:

```
function UserSearchPage() {
  const [criteria, setCriteria] = useState('');
  const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState('');

  const [loadUsers, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery);

  function PrintUsers({ data }: any) {
    return (
      <div>
        {data &&
          data.users.nodes &&
          data.users.nodes.map((c: any, i: any) => (
            <li key={i}>
              Id: {c.id}, First Name: {c.firstName}, Last Name: {c.lastName},
              Email: {c.email}, phoneNumber: {c.phoneNumber}
            </li>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  let ShowUsers = () => {
    const where: WhereInput = {};
    if (criteria === '1') {
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: where
        },
      });      
    }

    if (criteria === '2') {
      if (searchItem) {
        where.firstName_contains = searchItem;
        loadUsers({
          variables: {
            where: where
          },
        });
      }
    }
  };
  return (
.....);
}
```

This is how the GraphQL query itself looks like:

```
interface UserFilter {
  email_contains: String;
  firstName_contains?: String;
  lastName_contains?: String;
  phoneNumber_contains?: String;
  id?: Number;
}
export const LoadUsersQuery = gql`
  query usersList($where: UserFilter) {
    users(where: $where) {
      nodes {
        id
        email
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
`;
```

How else can I access the data properties/errors?
From the console.log, I know that this is returned:

```
Object

__typename: "User"

email: "first@first.com"

firstName: "First"

id: 148

lastName: "User"

phoneNumber: "+49123"
```

But if I try to access lets say `data.users.id`, why do I get undefined? How can I fix this?

Comment: where is `loadUsers`?

Comment: Question updated @Wyck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in other answers, it's known problem - ["useLazyQuery execution function should return a promise #3499"](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3499#)

Instead of

```
    loadUsers({
      variables: {
        where: where
      },
    })
    .then(({ data }: any) => {
      if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
      }
    })
```

you can use `onCompleted` option

```
const [loadUsers, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery, {
  onCompleted: ( data : any ) => {
    if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
      // some action
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Since I am using loadUsers query multiple times (every time with different parameters), I'm not sure if this would be feasible.

Comment: I tried adding ```{ loading, data, error }``` but if I do ```console.log('Error: ' , error);``` after the loadUsers query ends, I always get undefined. Even when there is an error. What's the right way to use it? I couldn't find any relevant example.

Comment: you can call mutation with different variables from multiple places - data handling is usually the same ... `loading` can be undefined if `data` is ok

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. How else can I access the error message then? Also, for example, the query returns an object with the property ```id```so how can I access the property? In case of mutations, I would just do ```data.loadUsers.id```or something and it would work but not in this case. So what's the solution?

Comment: `error` is available in component fn body (like you tried earlier) ... id? check response/console.log it? ... `data.id`?

Comment: Error comes as undefined. And data.id also throws an error that undefined is not an object. data.users.nodes returns an object but if I append .id to it, it doesn't work.

Comment: if it is an array then itarate on it `...nodes[0].id` ... all this you can check - response is a JSON - check it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly is happening in `loadUsers`, but it's likely that you've forgotten to a return statement there.

If you change `loadUsers` to return the promise for the user's it's loading, your code should start working nicely.

Comment: loadUsers is a graphql query. I don't think I need a return statement there, do I? Like in the first example, updateUser() is also a graphql mutation and it works correctly. Could you see my updated qs and then explain what you meant?

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct. Buried in op's example though is that `loadUsers` is coming from an external method, `useLazyQuery` provided by Apollo. The method returned doesn't return a Promise.

Comment: So how else can I access the error message then? Also, for example, the query returns an object with the property ```id```so how can I access the property? In case of mutations, I would just do ```data.loadUsers.id```or something and it would work but not in this case. So what's the solution? @LMulvey

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#result-1) for `useLazyQuery`, it does not return a `Promise` like `useMutation` so they behave differently.

Instead of relying on a Promise, you must utilize the second parameters (loading, data) returned when invoking `useLazyQuery`. This is why in your edit, your code works without the `.then`.

Comment: I tried adding ```{ loading, data, error }``` but if I do ```console.log('Error: ' , error);``` after the loadUsers query ends, I always get undefined. Even when there is an error. What's the right way to use it? I couldn't find any relevant example.